# error updating to meteor 1.3.4.4

Tags: meteor

Meteor instructed to do meteor update from 1.3.4.3 to update to 1.3.4.4 and after I did that, I got the following errors.
Not sure what to do at this point, any idea? Thanks

```
$meteor update
  => Errors
while initializing project:

  While loading package fourseven: scss@ 3.3.3_3:
  error: Command failed:
  module.js: 340
throw err; ^
Error: Cannot find module '../'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename(module.js: 338: 15)
at Function.Module._load(module.js: 280: 25)
at Module.require(module.js: 364: 17)
at require(module.js: 380: 17)
at Object. < anonymous >
  (/Users/empl1 / .meteor / packages / fourseven_scss / .3.3.3_3.ecnkm4++os.osx.x86_64 + web.browser + web.cordova / plugin.compileScssBatch.os.osx.x86_64 / npm / node_modules / meteor / compileScssBatch / compileScssBatch / node_modules / .temp - 1dptekz / node_modules / node - sass / node_modules / cross - spawn / node_modules / spawn - sync / node_modules /
    try -thread - sleep / node_modules / thread - sleep / node_modules / .bin / node - pre - gyp: 15: 20)
at Module._compile(module.js: 456: 26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js(module.js: 474: 10)
at Module.load(module.js: 356: 32)
at Function.Module._load(module.js: 312: 12)
at Function.Module.runMain(module.js: 497: 10)

npm ERR!Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR!argv "node"
"/Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.hzx8lp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild"
"--no-bin-links"
"--update-binary"
npm ERR!node v0.10.46
npm ERR!npm v3.10.5
npm ERR!code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!thread - sleep@ 1.0.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install
--fallback-to-build`
npm ERR!Exit status 8
npm ERR!
  npm ERR!Failed at the thread - sleep@ 1.0.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp
install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR!Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
installed.
npm ERR!If you do,
  this is most likely a problem with the
thread - sleep package,
  npm ERR!not with npm itself.
npm ERR!Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!node - pre - gyp install--fallback - to - build
npm ERR!You can get information on how to open an issue
for this
project with:
  npm ERR!npm bugs thread - sleep
npm ERR!Or
if that isn 't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls thread-sleep
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
/Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.3.3_3.ecnkm4++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os.osx.x86_64/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1dptekz/npm-debug.log

module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '.. / '
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>
(/Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.3.3_3.ecnkm4++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os.osx.x86_64/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1dptekz/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync/node_modules/try-thread-sleep/node_modules/thread-sleep/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp:15:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node"
"/Users/empl1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.5_1.hzx8lp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v0.10.46
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! thread-sleep@1.0.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install
--fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the thread-sleep@1.0.4 install script '
node - pre - gyp
install--fallback - to - build '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the
thread-sleep package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs thread-sleep
npm ERR! Or if that isn'
t available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!npm owner ls thread - sleep
npm ERR!There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR!Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!
  /Users/empl1 / .meteor / packages / fourseven_scss / .3.3.3_3.ecnkm4++os.osx.x86_64 + web.browser + web.cordova / plugin.compileScssBatch.os.osx.x86_64 / npm / node_modules / meteor / compileScssBatch / compileScssBatch / node_modules / .temp - 1dptekz / npm - debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a magration from a lesser version of Meteor 1.2 to a 1.3+.

Warnings are related to this package:[meteor-scss](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss)

On its documentation it recommends to do the following for 1.3+ versions.

`meteor remove standard-minifier-css
meteor add seba:minifiers-autoprefixer`

If that does'nt work it also talks about locking a version for specific Meteor Versions

> Note: Due to same changes between Meteor 1.3.0-1.3.1 and Meteor 1.3.2+, Users of Meteor 1.3.0 or 1.3.1 are advised to use version 3.4.2 of fourseven:scss

You can do this inside ./meteor/versions folder.

Comment: 1.3.4.3 is the current version, which is the version before the update, as the update failed thus nothing updated and back to the version which was there before the attempt to update.