# fourseven:scss problems with meteor upgrade

Tags: meteor

My current Meteor version is 1.3.4.3 running on MacBook with El Capitan, it failed to upgrade while loading fourseven: scss@ 3.3.3_3 with the error as in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38448311/5047454)

And this did not fix the error:
`meteor remove standard-minifier-css`
`meteor add seba:minifiers-autoprefixer`

So I did `meteor remove fourseven:scss` as I am not sure if I needed it and run the upgrade again but still the same error.

How can I fix it so the upgrade works? Thanks

```
$meteor update
  => Errors
while initializing project:

  While loading package fourseven: scss@ 3.3.3_3:
  error: Command failed:
  module.js: 340
throw err; ^
Error: Cannot find module '../'
```

**edit**

When I change the line `fourseven:scss@3.3.3_3` in ./meteor/versions to `fourseven:scss@3.4.2` and run the `meteor update`, I get the error

```js
$meteor update
  => Errors
while initializing project:

  While downloading fourseven: scss@ 3.4.2...:
  error: Command failed:
  module.js: 340
throw err; ^
Error: Cannot find module '../'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename(module.js: 338: 15)
at Function.Module._load(module.js: 280: 25)
at Module.require(module.js: 364: 17)
at require(module.js: 380: 17)
at Object. < anonymous >
  (/private/var / folders / 8y / 63
```

Comment: That is weird. I'm working with Meteor 1.3.5.1 and using fourseven:scss 3.8.0_1. Everythings work fine for me. Did you try to upgrade your version? execute meteor list to check which version you are currently using

Comment: @JulienLeray `meteor list` did not reveal any 'fourseven' package, do I need it? should I add it?

Comment: hum. Nothing wrong with the fact you don't have `fourseven` package on your `meteor list`; you removed it. I just don't get why your meteor try to update this package tho. Did you try to simply re install the package? Run a simple `meteor add fourseven:scss `and let see.

Comment: @JulienLeray I tried and re installed the package for no avail. Still the same error as originally posted.

Comment: same error? Still talking about the 3.3.3_3 version of `fourseven`?Can you now see the package after with `meteor list`?

Comment: @JulienLeray Yes. It is there in the list.

Comment: @JulienLeray and it is 3.3.3_3 even though there is an updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the following fixed the problem:

```
meteor remove fourseven:scss
meteor add fourseven:scss@3.8.0_1
meteor update
```